# R- splitting dataframe column with string values (containing 2 numbers and separated by a comma) into 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `ddata` where the variable `Location` has the Latitude and Longitude in string format separated by a comma. So when I type `ddata$Location` into my console I see this:

```
"33.9829, -118.3338"
"34.0454, -118.3157"
"33.942,  -118.2717"
"33.9572, -118.2717"
```

How do I separate this column by the comma, a delimiter, and get it to become 2 columns called: `Longitude` and `Latitude`? I have tried the split function but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is separated by `,`, the easiest option is `read.csv` (assuming that the class of 'Location' is `character` and not `factor`.  If it is factor, convert it to `character` (with `as.character(ddata$Location)`)

```
out <- read.csv(text = ddata$Location, header = FALSE,
      col.names = c("Latitude", "Longitude"))
```

Now, we `cbind` it with the original data

```
ddataNew <- cbind(dddata, out)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess this should work but it was taking forever to execute on my dataset of 1.5 million datapoints

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str_split_fixed` function in the `stringr` package, like this:

```
library(stringr)
ddata[,c("Longitude", "Latitude")] <- str_split_fixed(ddata$Location, ", ", 2)
```

It will give you:

```
#             Location  Longitude   Latitude
# 1 33.9829, -118.3338    33.9829  -118.3338
# 2 34.0454, -118.3157    34.0454  -118.3157
# 3  33.942, -118.2717     33.942  -118.2717
# 4 33.9572, -118.2717    33.9572  -118.2717
```

---

Then, if you want to remove the `Location` column, you can just use this:

```
ddata$Location <- NULL
```

To get this:

```
#   Longitude   Latitude
# 1   33.9829  -118.3338
# 2   34.0454  -118.3157
# 3    33.942  -118.2717
# 4   33.9572  -118.2717
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This did it really fast

Answer (score 1):

`library(tidyr)
separate(ddata, ddata$Location, c("Longitude", "Latitude"), ",")`